# Roslyn Recompile Slow

Tags: asp.net-core

I have seen many videos of code changes to a controller and then refreshing the page showing the update very quickly (1-2 seconds) and everyone is always talking about how fast Roslyn is.

I have just installed VS2014 CTP3, created a web application, hit run and then edited the message Contact action method returns.

When I hit refresh in my browser, the page takes about seconds to load (the first time, after that its instant). This the app pool starting back up and recompiling the code, but this seems a lot slower than what I have seen others experiencing.

Is anyone else having this? Could it be doing a full recompile rather than a partial recompile each time? Does anyone know how I can find out what is causing the slowness?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think most of the time the speed of Roslyn is compared to the speed of the previous source to il compiler. In the previous version of .NET you always pre compiled everything to il (a .net dll) which will always be somewhat slower than not pre compiling. This performance loss might be mitigated by performance gains in the il to native engine which is currently also being optimized. Depending how much needs to be compiled, jit compilation might still be to slow for your situation, so you might need to pre compile some files and or libraries.

Looking at recent merged pull requests and the fact that Roslyn is still in beta you might see considerable performance gains between the current alfa release and the RTM.

https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/pull/522
https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/498

Comment: Interesting, that second link seems the most relavent to me and it is tagged alpha4. The current project template is vs2014ctp3 seems to be using alpha3 so I will give alpha4 a try and see if that fixes it. Thanks